# macOS, .editrc and vi-mode

Tags: python, vi, editline

According to `man editrc`, you have to put `bind -v` in your `~/.editrc` file to enable vi-like mappings in software that uses `editline`. Which in its turn will allow you to press `<Esc>v` there to launch vi itself.

But is it possible to tell a REPL (I'm talking about python specifically if that matters) to launch **Vim** on that keypress, not **vi**? I have an old version of Vim 7.3 aliased under `vi`, which isn't exactly very helpful these days, but I still would like to keep it that way...

(Just in case, in Bash, it uses `$EDITOR`  variable when launching an editor, and therefore works just fine.)